# Objective function and Neighborhood function

Tags: algorithms

I have a problem which has several solution but one is the optimal .
my questions are:

1- It is required to write an objective function. I don't know what "Objective Function" mean . I need the definition of this function regard my problem.

2-Another requirement is writing a Neighborhood function of a local search algorithm, also i need the definition for this function.

Thank you

Comment: Your question is not answerable as it stands. I strongly suggest you review the course material.

Comment: [Objective function on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_function). Please do some basic research before asking others to do it for you!

Answer (score 2):

An *objective function* is some function that returns a value indicating how 'close' a given solution is to the optimal solution. This might be an exact value, or an estimate.

A *neighbourhood function* is a function that returns a list, set, etc. of the states that are considered 'adjacent' to the current state: that is, states that can be obtained by making a single modification to the current state according to whatever rules are appropriate to your problem.

To illustrate: suppose you are trying to navigate from one city to another. Your 'states' are the individual cities that you can travel through, and they are connected in such a way as to represent which cities are adjacent to each other. Your objective function could be a measure of how far a given city is from your target city; the lower the value the closer to optimal it is. Your neighbourhood function would then return the list of all cities connected to your current city (i.e. cities reachable in one step).